# Compute the limit $\lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{\cosh(x+1)}{e^x}$

Tags: real-analysis, limits

I'm trying to compute the following limit, and hope for some feedback to my appoach

$\lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{\cosh(x+1)}{e^x}$

I've tried rearranging the equation, by deciding that $\cosh(x+1)$ = $\frac{e^x+e^{-x}}{2}+1$, though correct me if this is not right.

I've tried simplifying the equation likeso:

$$\frac{\left(\frac{e^x+e^{-x}}{2}+1\right)}{e^x}=\frac{e^x+e^{-x}+2}{2e^x}$$

Then by taking the derivative according to L'hopitals rule:

$$\frac{d}{dx}\frac{e^x+e^{-x}+2}{2e^x}=-\frac{e^{-x}+1}{e^x}$$

Though, I'm not sure if L-hopitals rule applied to this, I know that:

$\lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{x}{e^x}=0$, and $\lim_{x\to\infty}e^{-x}=0$; Then the limit above must tend to 0?

Comment: how is that cosh(x+1)? That is cosh(x)+1, what you've written

Comment: You are confusing $\cosh(x+1)$ with $\cosh(x)+1$

Comment: Simply replacing $cosh(x+1) = \frac{e^{x+1} + e^{-x-1}}{2}$ should yield the right approach to obtain the value of $\frac{e}{2}$ for the limit in an arguably straightforward manner for you. :)

Comment: You all right! Thank you all for the correction. This has helped me towards any future mistakes on this